# reading ffmpeg output and sending it to a form

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, stderr

I can run arguments through ffmpeg just fine, but I need to be able to read its output LIVE as it streams (as you may know, ffmpeg can take a while, and it updates its stderr twice a second with current frame, etc).

I have a form called `prog` that was declared globally with `ProgressForm prog = new ProgressForm();`  The user inputs a folder of video files, some data is gathered, and then a button is pushed to start the encoding process with ffmpeg.  The button_click event creates a new thread like so:

```
 runFFMpeg = new Thread(run_ffmpeg);
 runFFMpeg.start();
```

runFFMpeg was initialized globally earlier with `private Thread runFFMpeg;`.

Now I have the method run_ffmpeg:

```
private void run_ffmpeg()
{
    string program = "C:\\ffmpeg64.exe";
    string args = //some arguments that I know work;

    ProcessStartInfo run = new ProcessStartInfo(program,args);
    run.UseShellExecute = false;
    run.CreateNoWindow = true;
    run.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    run.RedirectStandardError = true;
    Process runP = new Process();
    runP = Process.Start(run);
    runP.WaitForExit();

    //NOW WHAT?

 }
```

I'm not sure what to do now to get the data LIVE, but if I can, I would be updating `prog`, which has a number of controls, including progress bars, etc.  Typical output (that I'm interested in) looks like "frame= 240 fps= 12.8 q=0.0 size=   1273802kB time=00:00:08.008 bitrate=4415.2kbits/s dup=46 drop=0".  I know how to parse that to get what I need, I just need that line!

Answer (score 0):

```cs
run.Start();
StreamReader sr = run.StandardError;
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
    string output = sr.ReadLine();
}
run.WaitForExit();
```

string *output* will be your line.